# Creating Second uiview without IB or Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Would someone be so kind as to point out where this tutorial is steering me wrong?

Open up the -SECOND- project you made and change the name of:

```
RootViewController.h
RootViewController.mm
```

To:

```
SecondView.h
SecondView.mm
```

Now, open up SecondView.h and change the following code:

```
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController {

}
@end
```

To:

```
@interface SecondView: UIViewController {

}
```

@end

Save and close SecondView.h and open up SecondView.mm. In SecondView.mm, let's change the following code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
```

To:

```
#import "SecondView.h"
```

And change the following code:

```
@implementation RootViewController
```

To:

```
@implementation SecondView
```

**Part 2:** Set up the view controller

Save and close SecondView.mm. In iFile, cut both SecondView.h and SecondView.mm and paste them into the testview project folder. Open your Makefile, and on the line:

testview_FILES = main.m testviewApplication.mm

Edit that line to look like:

testview_FILES = main.m testviewApplication.mm SecondView.mm

This will compile SecondView.mm into an object file (SecondView.o) and add it to the finalized testview binary (testview.app > testview). And guess what? That's how you set up a new class for your projects! Proceed to part 3!

**Part 3:** Set it up in-app (Usage)

So you have a new UIViewController and UIView ready to be used whenever you want huh? Well now we will call our view controller to present our amazingness view! With the shiny code:

```
 //Bring SecondView to memory (RAM)
    SecondView *second= [[[SecondView alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Properties for second (SecondView)
    second.title = @"UINavigationBar";
    //Present second (SecondView) to user
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

Now that you have the ability to bring another view up front, a question you want to ask yourself is whether or not you want the user to be able to go back to the RootViewController. If not, then just skip this step. Using the action property of either UIButtons or UIBarButtonItems to UIAlertViews or UIActionSheets, you can call this whenever needed.
The problem is that my build is throwing an error of "SecondView was not declared in this scope" and "second was not declared here". Every other part of this tutorial has worked perfectly so I am assuming there's a typo here in Step 3 just above the code. I'm just jumping into apps developing and do not have the luxury of Xcode or many tutorials without Xcode. EVERYTHING HAS BEEN FOLLOWED TO THE LETTER. Thanks.

Comment: Please Format your question properly.

Comment: Why are you trying to build an app without Xcode? Can you provide a link to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: The web link to this tutorial is dead, it's from a theos tutorial app. Xcode would require a Mac which I'm not in possession of. Theos is capable of building apps on an iOS device. Consider it getting my feet wet before diving into a $2,000 machine and developers license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your RootViewController.mm file

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondView.h"
@implementation RootViewController

  - (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(21, 80, 100, 35);
   [myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:myButton];

}

  - (void)myButtonPressed {
    SecondView *second= [[[SecondView alloc] init] autorelease];
    second.title = @"UINavigationBar";
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Very helpful seeing the code in action